# XOR on integer array

Tags: octave

For example I have `array = [2   2   3   4   5   4   1   5]` and I want to drop all the numbers that are not 2 from the array, how would I accomplish that?

I wanted something like XOR but for decimals.
For example:

`xor(array,2) = [2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple example of standard Matlab trick - **Logical Indexing** (see [Using Logicals in Array Indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html)):

```
array = [2   2   3   4   5   4   1   5];
array(array != 2) = 0;
isequal(array, [ 2   2   0   0   0   0   0   0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfamiliar with Octave so I don't know if the lambda would work but something like this?

```
A = [2   2   3   4   5   4   1   5]
arrayfun(@(x) x == 2, A) // A = [1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0]
arrayfun(@(x) x * 2, A)  // A = [2   2   0   0   0   0   0   0]
```

Answer (score 0):

@SergV has a good answer, but when you say drop from the array, do you want them to be zero'd out as he did, or removed?

From his answer:

```
array = [2   2   3   4   5   4   1   5];
array(array != 2) = 0
array =
2   2   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

but similarly, this will 'drop out' the other numbers:

```
array = [2   2   3   4   5   4   1   5];
array(array != 2) = []
array =
2   2
```

also, note that in either case, you can replace the `(array != 2)` part with a more complex expression.  You mentioned wanting this to work for decimals. Using `==` or `!=` you could run into issues with floating point precision. If the values from `array` are not defined precisely by you, you may need test for a range of values.  For example:

```
array = [2   2   3   4   5   4   1];
eps
ans =   2.2204e-016

array = array + 10*eps; ##disturb the values to demonstrate the issue
array(array != 2) = 0    
array =
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Instead you'll need to test for a range of values, and accept those within an acceptable error bound.

```
error_range = 1e-9; ##set some arbitrary range to accept
target_value = 2; 

array_vals = (array > target_value-error_range)&(array < target_value+error_range)
array_vals =
1   1   0   0   0   0   0

array(~array_vals) = 0
array =
2.00000   2.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
```

Last, note that I believe just using == or ~= will work as long as the values are within `eps` of the number you ask for.  I.e., just adding `eps` to the values, it should still work using the original solution.